# Что означает ключевое слово base при наследовании?

Tags: c#

```
public class DemandAccount : Account
    {
        public DemandAccount(decimal sum, int percentage) : base (sum, percentage)
        {

        }
    }
```

Что значит base (sum, percentage) ?

Comment: Это значит использовать конструктор базового класса(Account), и передать в него аргументы из конструктора текущего класса(DemandAccount).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключевое слово `base` используется для доступа к членам базового из производного класса в следующих случаях:

- Вызов метода базового класса, который был переопределен другим методом.
- Определение конструктора базового класса, который должен вызываться при создании экземпляров производного класса.

Доступ к базовому классу разрешен только в конструкторе, методе экземпляра или методе доступа к свойству экземпляра.
Использование ключевого слова `base` в статическом методе является недопустимым.
Доступ осуществляется к базовому классу, заданному в объявлении класса. Например, если указать `class ClassB : ClassA`, члены `ClassA` будут доступны из `ClassB` независимо от базового класса `ClassA`.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    int num;
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass()");
    }
    public BaseClass(int i)
    {
        num = i;
        Console.WriteLine("in BaseClass(int i)");
    }
}    
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Этот конструктор вызовет BaseClass.BaseClass()
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {}
    // Этот конструктор вызовет BaseClass.BaseClass(int i)
    public DerivedClass(int i) : base(i)
    {}
    static void Main()
    {
        DerivedClass md = new DerivedClass();    //Вывод: in BaseClass()
        DerivedClass md1 = new DerivedClass(1);  //Вывод: in BaseClass(int i)
    }
}
```